# add mailto and http tag in ancher tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, data-structures

I want to add the mailto and http value in the anchor tag. I tried to build regex but i'm not able to handle these two case at a time.

```
ex1. -> "this is test mail <mailto:demomail@gmail.com|demomail@gmail.com> testend"
output -> "this is test mail <a href=mailto:demomail@gmail.com>demomail@gmail.com</a> testend"

ex2. -> "hello <http://google.com|google.com> hello"
output -> "hello <a href=http://google.com>google.com</a> hello"
```

Guys, is there any any we can handle these string using any regex,gsub method or any other method?

i'm trying `gsub(/<mailto:([^|]*)[^>]*>/, '<a href=#)}')` but couldn't able to complete this? I'm not able to understand how can we handle above cases.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? What is the "anchor tag"? As I understand you want to format the input string saving domain from a link if the string contains the http link or save the first email address if the string contains mailto link?  Can the string contain both types of links?

Comment: @Alexey Zalyotov yes string can contains both type of email. anchor tag means here. in the input string as you can see i'm seeing the "<mailto:demomail@gmail.com|demomail@gmail.com>" but when i open this thing in the browser it will not behave like a link. so i want to convert this thing to "<a href=mailto:demomail@gmail.com>demomail@gmail.com</a>" something like this so once i open this in browser it will redirect me to to mail. and for http case it will redirect me to the given url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use 2 capture groups for the one that starts with `<mailto:`

```
<(mailto:[^\s@|]+@[^\s@|]+)\|([^\s@|]+@[^\s@|>]+)>
```

**Explanation**

- `<` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `mailto:` Match literally
  - `[^\s@|]+@[^\s@|]+` Match an email like format
- `)` Close group 1
- `\|` Match `|`
- `([^\s@|]+@[^\s@|>]+)` Capture **group 2**, match an email like format
- `>` Match literally

In the replacement use `<a href=\1>\2</a>`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/etbHVK/1) | [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/lahZYk)

```
re = /<(mailto:[^\s@|]+@[^\s@|]+)\|([^\s@|]+@[^\s@|>]+)>/
str = 'this is test mail <mailto:demomail@gmail.com|demomail@gmail.com> testend'
subst = '<a href=\1>\2</a>'

puts str.gsub(re, subst)
```

Output

```
this is test mail <a href=mailto:demomail@gmail.com>demomail@gmail.com</a> testend
```

For the second example, you can use the same approach with 2 capture groups:

```
<(https?:\/\/[^\s|]+)\|([^\s>]+)>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rROUHx/1)

---

For a pattern that can match both scenario's with the same replacement, you can just use the `|` char as the delimiter and match either `mailto:` or `https://`

```
<((?:mailto:|https?:\/\/)[^\s|]+)\|([^\s|]+)>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dGNY4o/1)

Output

```
this is test mail <a href=mailto:demomail@gmail.com>demomail@gmail.com</a> testend
hello <a href=http://google.com>google.com</a> hello
```

Comment: @The_foruth_bird thanks for your amazing answer. In addition to that can we form one regex where we can handle these both cases.

Comment: @ShantiLalPrajapat I have added an update to the answer with a pattern that can match both scenario's.